# How Do I properly Use Check Boxes with wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl.CustomTreeCtrl Styles?

Tags: checkbox, wxpython, multi-select, treecontrol

I wanted to add check boxes to a multi selection  tree control that I was using, and I thought that I could do this with...

```
import wx, wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl

app = wx.App(False)

fr = wx.Frame(None)

myModule = wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl
myStyle = (myModule.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE|myModule.TR_MULTIPLE
           |myModule.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT|myModule.TR_AUTO_CHECK_CHILD
           |myModule.TR_AUTO_CHECK_PARENT|myModule.TR_AUTO_TOGGLE_CHILD)

tree = myModule.CustomTreeCtrl(fr, style=myStyle)
treeRoot = tree.AddRoot("PyRx Enzymes")
treeNodes =['Node A','Node B', 'Node C']
treeItems = ['1', '2', '3']
for i, _ in enumerate(treeNodes):
    iNode = tree.AppendItem(treeRoot, treeNodes[i])
    for ii in treeItems:
        tree.AppendItem(iNode, "%s %s"%(treeNodes[i].replace('Node ',''), ii) )
tree.Expand(treeRoot)

fr.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

...However changing the style options does not seem to have any effect. No matter how I change the 'myStyle' variable I end up with the same results that I get when setting it to 0. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am using wxPython 2.9 on 64-bit Windows 7.

EDIT: I see that I was using the 'style' named parameter instead of 'agwStyle.'

Answer (score 1):

My apologies on overlooking the obvious. The below code creates the desired functionality.

```
import wx, wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl

app = wx.App(False)

fr = wx.Frame(None)

myModule = wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl
myStyle = (myModule.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE|myModule.TR_MULTIPLE
           |myModule.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT|myModule.TR_AUTO_CHECK_CHILD
           |myModule.TR_AUTO_CHECK_PARENT|myModule.TR_AUTO_TOGGLE_CHILD)

tree = myModule.CustomTreeCtrl(fr, agwStyle=myStyle)
treeRoot = tree.AddRoot("PyRx Enzymes")
treeNodes =['Node A','Node B', 'Node C']
treeItems = ['1', '2', '3']
for i, _ in enumerate(treeNodes):
    iNode = tree.AppendItem(treeRoot, treeNodes[i], ct_type=1)
    for ii in treeItems:
        tree.AppendItem(iNode, "%s %s"%(treeNodes[i].replace('Node ',''), ii), ct_type=1)
tree.Expand(treeRoot)

fr.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Any suggestions on possible improvements would be appreciated.